# Adding visual studio project to AOT

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a built a class library in visual studio 2010 which I want to add to my AOT and then use it to build my own service. I added the library to the AOT by right clicking it and pressing Add ClassLibray1 to AOT. I can see the library in the AOT (Visual Studio Project -> C Sharp Projects). But when a add a new class to the AOT and try to use this library, the intellisense does not show it. The dll is present is in the Client->Bin folder. I have tried restarting the AOS and building the dll again. How do I proceed?

Comment: Any solution ppl! still stuck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with assemblies in AX 2012 has changed comparing to AX 2009. One of the key points is - now there is no need to copy assemblies to client/server "bin" folder, thus (just an  assumption) if you copied an assembly manually - delete it from "bin" folder(-s).

Please read

- [Visual Studio Development for Microsoft Dynamics AX [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889157.aspx). There is an article [Deploying Managed Code [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg889192.aspx) which describes VS project properties for deployment.
- detailed description how deployment works - http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/09/ax-2012-net-assembly-deployment.html

Usually you have to do following steps (to make VS project's class(-s) available in X++ editor):

- add project from VS to AOT
- set project properties in VS: "Deploy to client" & "Deploy to server"
- (optional) restart AX client (if you had it opened, while you were adding VS project to AOT)

Now you can consume your assembly from AX.

Comment: Thanx a lot :) I had missed setting the project properties. Works now :)

Comment: There are some issue deploying the DLL files. But the safest way is to use the Global Assembly Cache. (Check http://www.ksaelen.be/wordpresses/dynamicsaxblog/2013/05/ax2012-dll-deployment-and-how-ax-binds-dlls-at-runtime/ for a full explanation on how AX retrieves DLL assemblies at runtime)